# How can I combine three columns with the same name based on ID?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have such a table:

```
ID  FIELD ID VALUE
100  1       Sir
100  2       Alex
100  3       Ferguson
```

I want to combine those three in a single column called `value`. It will be Sir Alex Ferguson.

Those three records sharing the same ID which is 100. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this.

```
        select id, group_concat(`VALUE` separator ' ') as `VALUE`
        from tableName
        group by id;
```

OR

```
       select id, group_concat(`VALUE` order by `FIELD ID` separator ' ') as `VALUE` from
        (                          
        select 100 'ID', 1 'FIELD ID', 'sir' as 'VALUE' union
        select 100 , 2  ,  'Alex' union
        select 100 , 3   ,   'Ferguson'
            )a
        group by id;
```

Comment: Without an ORDER BY in the GROUP_CONCAT, the resulting value is indeterminate.  Could be returned as `Ferguson Alex Sir'  or 'Alex Sir Ferguson'. Any of those would be valid in terms of MySQL conforming to the specification.

Answer (score 3):

Use `GROUP_CONCAT` with `ORDER BY` option and separator as a space.

```
select id, group_concat(value order by field_id separator ' ')
from your_table
group by id;
```